# How to use Func with Entity Data Context?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework

i writed below codes MyCustomer.cs must return List which is type of Customer entity. İ used Func method. I want to do this:

```
return erpEntityCtx.Customer.Select(select).ToList<TResult>();
```

BUT error return to me:

**Has some invalid argument.**

i can use this:

```
return erpEntityCtx.Customer.Select(c=>c.Name).ToList<TResult>();
```

However i can not do this with DataContext How can i do that?

```
public class MyCustomer :  Manager.ILoad
    {


        #region ILoad Members


        public List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(Func<TKey, TResult> select)
        {
            using (Erp.DAL.ErpEntities erpEntityCtx = new Erp.DAL.ErpEntities())
            {
                return erpEntityCtx.Customer.Select(select).ToList<TResult>();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

```
namespace Erp.BLL.Manager
{

    public interface ILoad
    {
        List<TResult> Load<TKey,TResult>(List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select);
        List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(Func<TKey, TResult> select);
    }


    public interface IErpManager
    {
        List<TResult> Load<TKey,TResult>(ILoad erpObj, List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select);
        List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(ILoad erpObj, Func<TKey, TResult> select);

    }

    public class ErpManager : IErpManager
    {

        #region IErpManager Members

        public List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(ILoad erpObj, List<TKey> list, Func<TKey, TResult> select)
        {
            return erpObj.Load(list, select);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IErpManager Members


        public List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(ILoad erpObj, Func<TKey, TResult> select)
        {
            return erpObj.Load(select);
        }

        #endregion
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of your initial problems is that your ILoad interface is non-generic, but you have specified methods without generic constraints, e.g.

```
List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(Func<TKey, TResult> select);
```

Firstly, predicates must evaluate to true of false, so it should really be `Func<TModel, bool> select` where `TModel` is your entity type.

You are then trying to do this:

```
List<TResult> Load<TKey, TResult>(Func<TKey, TResult> select)
{
        using (Erp.DAL.ErpEntities erpEntityCtx = new Erp.DAL.ErpEntities())
        {
            return erpEntityCtx.Customer.Select(select).ToList<TResult>();
        }
}
```

Without specifying any constraints on your generic methods (or better yet, your generic class), you can't satisfy the Func with Func.

You need to potentially change to this:

```
public interface IRepository<TModel>
{
   List<TModel> Get(Func<TModel, bool> predicate);
}
```

And implement as:

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
    public List<Customer> Get(Func<Customer, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var context = new ErpEntities())
        {
             return context.Customers.Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

You should have a read up on the repository pattern.

Comment: but how can i do that :  public List<TModel> Get(IRepository<TModel> erpObj, Func<TModel, bool> predicate)
        {
            return erpObj.Get(predicate);
        }

Comment: i want to control from a manager class look above in my ques?

Comment: Why do you need to keep layering on top of it?